# Where does the name "AT-AT" come from?

Tags: star-wars

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport):

> The name "AT-AT" is never spoken in any of the films. Instead, the machines are referred to as "Imperial walkers."

So, where does the name **AT-AT** originate?

*(Of course, AT-AT stands for **All Terrain Armored Transport**, but neither term is in [the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223111136/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml).)*

Comment: Some sort of product placement by a big telecommunication company?

Comment: My memory from the time is that the name "AT-AT" went public *before* ESB was originally released, probably in some of the advance promo material, comics, etc; maybe even the novelisation (if that was released bfore the movie).  I'm almost certain that we knew what it was called when we first saw the movie.

Comment: I have to link to [this, which explains it so much better.](http://darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0967.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have not found anything about the real-life origin of the term AT-AT, but even if they were not named in the script, they were named by the time the [1981 Kenner toy line](https://web.archive.org/web/20170303051228/http://www.12back.com/vehicles/atat.php3) came out.

[image: Kenner AT-AT toy picture]

From the in-package catalog:

> Imagine you're DARTH VADER with your giant 17½" tall, 22" long AT-AT.
>   Legs can be posed and a lever moves head in any direction and also
>   makes the two laser cannons light up and pulsate. Two Action Figures
>   fit in the AT-AT's head. Two laser guns turn with a clicking sound.
>   Remove side door and the AT-AT can hold up to 10 Action Figures. Two
>   "C" batteries not included. Assembly required. Available Summer 1981.

Since I could not find any factual origin information, here are some speculative reasons:

1. By the time Empire was released, GL and team were writing the script
   for Jedi and they added different kinds of walkers to that movie.
   Now they needed a term to differentiate the different kinds of
   walkers.
2. Star Wars is heavily connected to merchandise. Since they have a toy based on everything from the movie, marketing might push them to come up with a Star Wars type name for everything in the movie.

Comment: Just looking at the box cover gives me a warm glowing feeling. How much do I want one of them...

Comment: "Imagine you're DARTH VADER"? As always, marketing gets it wrong. The Dark Lord of the Sith isn't an AT-AT commander :P

Comment: The AT-ST actually was in ESB, albeit very briefly.

Comment: @AndresF.: I'm imagining it now, in a conversation with marketing: *"You have failed me for the last time."*

Comment: @Wikis: poor ol' Veers is getting upstaged by Lord Vader all the time.

Comment: @Xantec - was the AT-ST in the original ESB? or only added in the special editions?

Comment: @HorusKol It was in the original version, seen in the background briefly during the Battle of Hoth.

Comment: @HorusKol [This image](http://i.imgur.com/v3ajs.png) I pulled from the bonus disc of the DVD edition of ESB that I have. _Supposedly_ it is the original, unmodified theatrical release; but I don't know if that is true or not (GL can't seem to leave well enough alone). Is there any way I can verify how true to original this copy is?

Comment: That is time index 0:30:24

Comment: @Xantec - it certainly looks like the original rather than a CG insert. I wish I knew where my 1990 remastered tapes were.

Comment: @Xantec you're right. I forgot that there were AT-STs in ESB.

Comment: @HorusKol I can confirm that the AT-ST walkers were on the original "See the original for the last time" boxset 90's VHS version. It's the only version I've ever seen and they were definitely in there.